# How do i dereference a pointer value passed as the empty interface?

Tags: pointers, go, interface

I've got a method taking a `target interface{}` on a type that I use for database access like:

```
func (c *client) Query(query someType, target interface{}) error {
    return c.db.Query(query).Decode(target)
}
```

This is then called like

```
result := resultType{}
if err := c.Query(myQuery, &result); err == nil {
    // do sth with result
}
```

Which does what I want it do as I am passing the pointer address of `result`

The trouble I am now running into is that I do not know how I can mock this kind of behavior (mutating the passed reference) in a test.

In case I wouldn't need to pass `interface{}` I could imagine it being done like this:

```
type mockClient struct {
    targetValue resultType
}

func (m *mockClient) Query(query someType, target *resultType) error {
    *target = m.targetValue
    return nil
}
```

If I try to do the same using my actual signature, I am not able to dereference the value contained in `target` like this:

```
type mockClient struct {
    targetValue interface{}
}

func (m *mockClient) Query(query someType, target interface{}) error {
    target = m.targetValue // this does not mutate the passed target
    return nil
}
```

Can I dereference a pointer value when it is passed in as the empty interface? In case it is not possible, what would be another approach of testing the side effects my method has without having to resort to concrete types as arguments?

Comment: You will have to use [reflection](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/), same as all of the unmarshallers that use the same technique of passing an `interface{}` output parameter.

Comment: Do you know a place in the stdlib where this is done and I could look it up? Or any other example?

Comment: As @Adrian mentioned, take a look at the unmarshallers, [example](https://golang.org/src/encoding/json/decode.go).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use 'reflect' package to do it.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

type mockClient struct {}

func (m *mockClient) Query(query string, target interface{}) error {
    a := "changed"
    va := reflect.ValueOf(a)
    reflect.ValueOf(target).Elem().Set(va)
    return nil
}

func main() {
    var mc mockClient
    target := "initial"
    mc.Query("qwe", &target)
    fmt.Println(target)
}
```

The simple example to reference you can find [here](https://play.golang.org/p/S7XllJpxLw1)

Comment: This answer helped me so much, thank you! For me, the value I was setting was also a pointer, so I had to do `va := reflect.ValueOf(a).Elem()`