# Pass an interface{} type with pointer value to an interface{} parameter

Tags: go, go-gin, go-echo

I have two function in my code, a parent function with `interface{}` parameter type and another child function with `interface{}` parameter type.
I called `childFunc` in `parentFunc` and assert parent param to `*interface{}` and pass it to `childFunc` and at the end i called parent function with `&user` argument

```
func childFunc(param interface{}){}

func parentFunc(param interface{}){
     childFunc(*(param.(*interface{})))
}

parentFunc(&user)
```

but i have this error:

```
interface conversion: interface {} is *models.User, not *interface {}
```

what is the problem?
how can i solve this problem?

this is my real code.

```
func Update(context echo.Context, modelUpdatedInstance interface{}, constraints map[string]interface{}) error {

    /* Validation */
    //test := modelUpdatedInstance.(*interface{})
    _, validationErrors := govalidator.ValidateStruct(*(modelUpdatedInstance.(*interface{})))
    if validationErrors != nil {
        return validation.CheckValidation(context, validationErrors)
    }

    if constraints != nil {
        database.DB.First(modelUpdatedInstance, constraints["id"]).Model(modelUpdatedInstance).Updates(modelUpdatedInstance)
    } else {
        return context.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, map[string]interface{}{"Errors": []string{"no identifier"}})
    }

    return context.JSON(http.StatusOK, *(modelUpdatedInstance.(*interface{})))
}
```

Comment: The error tells you exactly what is wrong. Your value is of type `*models.User`, not `*interface{}`, so trying to convert it to `*interface{}` fails. What is your question?

Comment: my child function only works on value only not reference, i intend to pass value of reference to child function. thanx for quick reply

Comment: Go always, only passes by value--there is no pass by reference in Go at all. So it seems you're trying to solve a problem that cannot exist.

Comment: @Flimzy so what if i want to pass reference?

Comment: @Flimzy if it pass as value?

Comment: You cannot pass by reference in Go. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/47296325/13860

Comment: @Flimzy i read that post, my problem is that i want to pass value of `user` to child function not `&user`(not pointer)

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: @MuffinTop for passing `user` value to child function i should assert it and  when assert it, it cause error

Comment: @Flimzy not pointer value only user value :)

Comment: @MuffinTop i insert code to question i want to insert value of `modelUpdatedInstance` in `ValidateStruct`

Comment: @BahmanBinary: So what's stopping you from using only a user value, and not a pointer value?

Answer (score 0):

The `govalidator.ValidateStruct` function expects a pointer to a struct. The top caller has a pointer to a struct.

Simply pass the pointer through the calls.

```
func top() {
    childFunc(&user{})
}

func parentFunc(param interface{}) {
    childFunc(param)
}

func childFunc(param interface{}) {
    _, err := govalidator.ValidateStruct(param)
    ...
}
```

[Run it on the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/HfyTwgFtz99).

Comment: i mean the question in this page: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49540367/how-do-i-dereference-a-pointer-value-passed-as-the-empty-interface   sorry for misleading you

Comment: is there any solution for that other than `reflect`

Comment: @BahmanBinary  It's unclear how `reflect` or the linked question relates to the question. It looks like you are attempting to dereference pointers where you should use the pointer value.  Remove the attempts to dereference the pointers from the code (including the type assertion) and try that. Report back with what does not work.